# Why calling a mutating method directly on ArraySlice doesn't trigger the copy-on-write?

Tags: arrays, swift, copy-on-write

Why calling a mutating method directly on ArraySlice doesn't trigger the copy-on-write? The only difference is assigning the slice to a variable, right?

My example codes:

```
var numbers = [15, 40, 10, 30, 60, 25, 5, 100]
numbers[0..<4].sort()
numbers
// [10, 15, 30, 40, 60, 25, 5, 100]
```

---

```
var n = numbers[4..<8]
n.sort()
numbers
// [10, 15, 30, 40, 60, 25, 5, 100]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? Any research?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you wrote:

```
var numbers = [15, 40, 10, 30, 60, 25, 5, 100]
numbers[0..<4].sort()
numbers
// [10, 15, 30, 40, 60, 25, 5, 100]
```

In this case, you directly act on a subset of the array. You sort (in place) the first 4 elements of the array ([0] to [3]). Then when you output `numbers`, you see that the first 4 elements are in sorted order.

```
var n = numbers[4..<8]
n.sort()
numbers
// [10, 15, 30, 40, 60, 25, 5, 100]
```

You then *copy* the next 4 elements of the array ([4] to [7]) into a *new* variable n. You then sort() n. Note that `numbers` is untouched.

Why were you expecting something different to happen?

Comment: numbers[0..<4] is a function call on a array which return a value of type ArraySlice, and n is also a value of type ArraySlice, the only difference is the latter has a name, and the two calls of sort have different outcome

Comment: Array slices are independent values, and mutating one does not affect the other: